# Incremental backups - rsync with hard links, or rsync to zfs with snapshots?

Tags: rsync, backup, zfs, hard-link

I need to set up a backup server to pull data from on-site linux servers.  The server will be running Ubuntu 16.04.

A requirement is to be able to access backups of files which have been subsequently deleted.

It needs to be reasonably, but not perfectly, space-efficient.  i.e. storing historic backups of slow changing servers shouldn't use much more space than the full backup does.

The two choices I'm looking at are:

- Using rsync and hardlinks - https://earlruby.org/2013/05/creating-differential-backups-with-hard-links-and-rsync/
- Using rsync to a ZFS filesystem, and creating ZFS snapshots

Are there reasons to choose one over the other?

Comment: Also related: http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/

Comment: `rsync` (plus `rsnapshot` or something for backup depth) works regardless of whether you have ZFS present

Comment: rsync to zfs + zfs snapshot will be **much** faster than rsync + hardlinks or rdiff-backup or similar.  and you also have all the advantages/features of ZfS - including compression, encryption, zfs send if you want a 2nd backup, etc.   Even de-duping if you want to waste money on extra RAM rather than more/bigger disks (disks, even SSDs, are far cheaper than RAM).  Also restoring deleted files or old versions of files from old snapshots is trivially easy with zfs (esp. if `snapdir` is set to `visible` so that you can work with the `.zfs/` subdir).

Comment: BTW, I used to use rdiff-backup a lot.  I still have some legacy rdiff-backup stuff (including on one of my zfs boxes)...mostly because changing it is low-priority.  I use rsync + zfs snapshot to backup non-zfs filesystems these days. (zfs gets backed up with `zfs send`).